# No fluid generated when baking data + baking mesh (2.90.1)

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation

trying to create an effect of blood dripping that will be late composited into a video.
I've tried changing the scale, resolution, particle min/max, but no matter what i do, baking the data+mesh on the domain does ostensibly nothing.

here is my .blend. Any help is appreciated

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e79pF90GDRhpCRtXR6Dy1S4-1wWk0pV7/view?usp=sharing

there is another object below the inflow object thats meant to throw the blood outward a bit, although i dont think that it is a factor

screenshot of workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When there's no emission, look first at the emitter (Circle, Inflow). Your "Circle" object, although converted to a mesh, may have insuffient surface areas to emit anything.  I checked the Is-Planar in the screen-cap below, and all started to work, even after reducing the Domain's Resolution from 200 to 100 (faster simulation, less accuracy).

[image]

[image]

I had a similar "dripping blood" for an animation.  It took some patience to get the effector animated to occasionally drip and not occasionally pour.   You might want a few, smaller circles with animated "Use Flow".  Or instead of a circle with "Is planar" (inaccurate), consider using a cylindar, and adjust the Z-dimenison (smaller == less flow).  Or continue to use your circle but scale X&Y.